# Simple examples implementing push notifications using latest Phonegap for iOS?

Tags: ios, cordova, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Anyone have a simple example or tutorial of how to implement push notifications using the latest version of Phonegap (3.1 or thereabouts) and current APN site? I've looked at Holly Schinsky' (DevGirl's Weblog), and while detailed, some of it's really out of date and there isn't one post with all the code required.

Would love a simple example showing all the steps required to implement in current Phonegap. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I recently implemented Push notification in Android and iOS for a Phonegap application using Plugins (Cordova-2.7.0). I followed the tutorials below. Hope it will help you too.

[Android Push notification Tutorial](http://devgirl.org/2012/10/25/tutorial-android-push-notifications-with-phonegap/)

[iOS Push notification Tutorial](http://devgirl.org/2012/10/19/tutorial-apple-push-notifications-with-phonegap-part-1/)

Comment: Is this supported for latest version of cordova? I am looking for android plugin

Comment: I have not tried the above plugins in cordova 3+. You can also try this...http://wait4ideas.wordpress.com/2014/04/29/push-notification-using-parse-js-sdk-and-phonegap/

Answer (score -1):

I dont know whether there is a much difference in implementing push for native apps or phonegap apps but have you tried **Amazon Push Service**, its very easy and available for iOS, Android, Windows etc. If you want to go for it, plz let me know.

Comment: I want to use it with phonegap

Comment: so thats what i said, i dont know whether there is much diff or not, but u can try AMAZON SNS PUSH SERVICES.